# Ring of integers versus polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I've no clue how to approach this problem: suppose $k=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is a number field where $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer of degree $n$, and let $\delta$ be the discriminant of a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis given by powers of $\alpha$, that is $\delta=\operatorname{discr}(\{1,\alpha,\dotsc,\alpha^{n-1}\})$. This basis, though it consists of algebraic integers, is not necessarily an integral basis for $k$. The apparent issue is that $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha] \subset \mathcal{O}_k$, but this containment may be strict as can be seen with some quadratic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$.

The exercise I'm looking at asks one to prove that one does have a containment in the other direction up to scaling, that $\mathcal{O}_k \subset \frac{1}{\delta}\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$. I'm not familiar enough with the requisite theory of abelian groups which is probably needed to explain this. Any hints?

Comment: A related problem: Suppose you have a copy $\Lambda$ of $\mathbf{Z}^2$ inside $\mathbf{Q}^2$ with generators $x$ and $y$. Now let $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ be integers, and let $u = ax+by$, $v = cx + dy$, and $\Lambda' = \{u,v\}$ so that $\Lambda \subset \Lambda'$.  Let $\delta$ be the determinant of the $2 \times 2$ matrix coming from $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$. Can you prove that $\Lambda \subset \frac{1}{\delta} \Lambda'$?

Comment: I see why what you suggest is true. I'll have to think harder about why it applies in my situation.

P.S. I assume you meant $\Lambda' \subset \Lambda$ originally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can say the following:

**Proposition:** Let $A$ be an integrally closed integral domain with field of fractions $K,$ and let $L/K$ be a finite separable extension. Let $B$ be the integral closure of $A$ in $L,$ and suppose that $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n\in L$ is a basis of $L/K$ with each $\alpha_i\in B.$ If $d = \operatorname{disc}(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n),$ then $dB\subseteq\sum_{i} A\alpha_i.$

Since you only want a hint, here's something to get you started: write an arbitrary element $b\in B$ as a $K$-linear combination of the $\alpha_i$'s. Consider the collection of $\alpha_j b$ as $j$ ranges from $1$ to $n.$ What do you get when you apply $\operatorname{Tr}_{L/K}$ to this system?

As a remark, here's an interesting corollary: you now have the containments $$d\mathcal{O}_K\subseteq\Bbb{Z}[\alpha]\subseteq\mathcal{O}_K.$$ Localizing away from $d$ gives you $$\Bbb{Z}[\alpha,d^{-1}] = \mathcal{O}_K[d^{-1}].$$

Comment: I assume you're leading me to the connection between trace and discriminant: if I have $b \in B$ written as $\sum x_k\alpha_k$ with coefficients $x_k \in K$, then $db = \det(\operatorname{Tr}(\alpha_i\alpha_j))\sum x_k\alpha_k$. But I don't see how this turns into an $A$-linear combination of the $\alpha_k$.

Comment: Hi @EthanDlugie; indeed, the point is that $d = \det\operatorname{Tr}(\alpha_i\alpha_j).$ However, if you begin with the system of equations $\alpha_j b = \sum_i \alpha_j\alpha_i x_i$ and take traces on both sides, you find $$\operatorname{Tr}(\alpha_j b)  = \sum_i\operatorname{Tr}(\alpha_i\alpha_j) x_i.$$ What does this tell you about the $x_i$?

Comment: Ah, I think I see. Since $\operatorname{Tr}(\alpha_j b) \in A$ as do $\operatorname{Tr}(\alpha_i\alpha_j)$ and $d=\det(\operatorname{Tr}(\alpha_i\alpha_j))$, you can invert the system to find each $x_i \in A$. Is that it?

Comment: @EthanDlugie you've got it!